# Save Shelf Dictionary-like object sorted by keys

Tags: python, ordereddictionary, shelve

I have huge dictionary with
    100 000 keys and large numpy arrays as values. And i want to save it as file for faster loading purposes.

I tried dumping it as pickle but I am running out of memory. Then tried json.dump but Numpy array as values is not supported.

Last I try with shelf but can't save it in order.

I have the following code:

```
with closing(shelve.open('file1.shelf', 'c')) as f:
     for id in ids:
         f[id] = np.array().shape(300, 27, 3)
```

I want to save the shelf like-dictionary object in Order with respect to the ids. So I would like to sort by id and then save it as file. 
Can I use OrderedDict on shelf object or I should use another way for this specific problem?

```
img_dic = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(f.items()))
```

Thanks!

Comment: What Python version are you using? When I try to reproduce your issue with Python 3.7, it saves the keys in order.

Comment: I am using Python3. But what did you do? Did you use collections.OrderedDict(sorted(f.items())) and if yes how ?

Comment: Which minor version? From CPython 3.6 on (Python 3.7+ guaranteed by the language) normal dictionaries preserve insertion order, so maybe it has something to do with that. I didn't use `OrderedDict` or anything like that.

Comment: Oh Yes! Indeed I use Python 3.5.2. Thanks! But how do I achieve the same in  Python 3.5.2?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a Numpy Dataframe from your dictionary of numpy arrays? The keys of the dict could be the index column. Dataframe would have multiple ways to be saved into disk.

maybe the `to_pickle` method there is more efficient. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html

Otherwise, you can save as parquet file or multiple other formats